# F# & Plivo - Could not load type "Plivo.API.RestAPI"

Tags: f#, plivo

I'm currently trying to write a simple F# app that will send a message from one number to another. I've been working around this error for a while but can't seem to get it working.

Here's what I have:

```
open Plivo.API
open RestSharp

let plivoApi = new RestAPI("MA***", "OT******");

let dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>()
dict.["src"] <- "1111111111"
dict.["dst"] <- "2222222222"
dict.["text"] <- "Hi, text from Plivo via the F sharp App."

let resp = plivoApi.send_message(dict)
printf "%s" (resp.ToString())
```

Here's the error:
[image]

Package versions:

RestSharp: v 105.2.3

Plivo: v 3.0.2

Any suggestions?

Comment: This code is working fine for me. What is your .NET?

Comment: @FoggyFinder I'm on 4.5.2 at the moment.

Comment: Hmm, I have tested it on .Net 4.0 .

Comment: Changed it to 4.0 and it worked. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at changing your .NET environment this could be the issue. Your code is working fine for me

Comment: What is your .NET?